# JavaScript Conditionals (if/else statements)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, conditional-statements

**Objective of the code:**

This JavaScript code will take a string input given by the user in input box, and it will check for some characters in the string by converting the string into numerous number of arrays , concatenating their members, and then using conditional statements.
 Then, depending on the result, it will call function(s) and store the functions' results in a variable/variables.

**Problem:**

Here's my JavaScript code:

```js
function start() {

  var one_one = document.getElementById("oneOne").value; // HTML : <tr><td><input type = "text" name = "one_one" id = "oneOne" value = " " /></td></tr>
  function logAnyBase(x, base) {
    var rslt = (Math.log(x)) / (Math.log(base));
    return rslt;
  }

  var result;
  var array = one_one.split("^");
  var arrayTwo = array[1].split("= ");
  var numberRaised = Number(array[0]);
  var equationEquals = Number(arrayTwo[1]);
  var arr = one_one.split('');
  var indexOfVariableX = arr.indexOf("x");
  var indexOfToThePowerOfSign = arr.indexOf("^");
  var variableX = arr[indexOfVariableX];
  var toThePowerOfSign = arr[indexOfToThePowerOfSign];
  var checkLogCase = toThePowerOfSign + variableX;

  if (checkLogCase == "^x") {

    result = logAnyBase(equationEquals, numberRaised);

  } else {

    var equation = algebra.parse(one_one); // a function from algebra.js, which converts string into a mathematical equation. Example: x + 2 = 3 
    result = equation.solveFor("x"); // this function finds the solution for x in this equation. For example: if the equation is x + 2 = 3, the solution is 1.
  }

  var final = document.getElementById("final"); // HTML: <h3 id = "final"></h3>
  final.innerHTML = "x = " + String(result);


}
```

```html
<script src = "https://algebrajs.000webhostapp.com/algebra-0.2.6.js"></script>

<div>
    <tr>
        <td>
         <input type = "text" name = "one_one" id = "oneOne" value = " "/>
     </td>
      
    </tr> 
     
    <br />
    <br />
     
    <button onclick = "start()">Solve</button>
          
    <h3 id = "final" style="color:black; overflow:scroll;"></h3>
  
   </div>
```

However, when I run the code, only the if block works, ignoring the else block. Whih means, if I include 2^x = 4 as an input, the result comes correct, which is , "x=2". But when I give something which doesn't have "^x" in it, such as "x + 2 = 3", then it does not return anything.

- At first I thought there was something wrong with the code in the else block, but when I remove the code in the "if" block, the code works fine. Which means if I give "x + 2 = 3" as an input, the result returns as expected, which is "x = 1" (Here I removed the part where it checks for "^x" in the input):

-

```
var one_one = document.getElementById("oneOne").value;
var equation = algebra.parse(one_one);
var result = equation.solveFor("x"); 
var final = document.getElementById("final"); 
final.innerHTML = "x = " + String(result);
```

- I also tried replacing "else" with another "if"  , but this time, the whole code stops working:

-

```
if(checkLogCase != "^x"){
    var equation = algebra.parse(one_one);
    result = equation.solveFor("x");
}
```

I want , that if I give "2^x = 4", the code will return "x = 2", and , if I give "x + 2 = 3" as an input, it will return "x = 1".

If I have any flaws in the question itself, kindly point them out.

Comment: `var arr = one_one.split('');` this line is unneccessary.

Comment: Please insert relevant libraries into the snippet I made for you

Comment: @JonasW.  What will I do with these then:                                                    var indexOfVariableX = arr.indexOf("x");
            var indexOfToThePowerOfSign = arr.indexOf("^");
            var variableX = arr[indexOfVariableX];
            var toThePowerOfSign = arr[indexOfToThePowerOfSign];

Comment: @mplungjan  these codes are already in my HTML

Comment: We really want a [mcve] which your snippet is NOT

Comment: All these work on strings too...

Comment: @mplungjan is my question right? And will I remove the snippet added by you?

Comment: UPDATE the snippet to a [mcve] - don't just add HTML somewhere. Click the "Edit snippet"

Comment: @mplungjan  I edited the snippet. However, the library I used ( http://algebra.js.org ) still doesn't have a cdn repository (I dont know why it doesn't , the library has more than 1000 stars in github), so I downloaded the library. Now, what can I do here?

Comment: @mplungjan  UPDATE: I hosted the library on my own domain. So now you can see the results.

Comment: @JonasW. Tried doing that, but it doesn't solve any problem.

Comment: Look in the console. Your code errors out if the string does not contain ^ - check the input or the length of array before failing on array[1].split(“=“)

Answer (score 0):

I realized that my problem was in line 11, where I wrote `var arrayTwo = array[1].split("= ");` . It should be `var arrayTwo = one_one.split("= ");`.

It could be that the .split() function doesn't support directly referring array element.

Thanks for your help anyways. :-)

Comment: As I commented, your split will fail if there is no ^ because then there is no array[1] and you will get an error - fee free to delete the question since it is very specifically your problem and is not understandable or useful for future visitors